# How to display and hide specific divs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple images on a page. Each image has an id associated with it. For each image, I want the user to be able to click on a heart. When the user clicks on a heart, the open heart icon should be replaced by the closed heart icon for just that image. Similarly, when a user unhearts an image, the closed heart icon should get replaced by the open heart icon.

I'm having trouble implementing this in javascript correctly. How would I reference just the icon that needs to be changed? Any advice on how to implement this?

Javascript

```
<script >
  function wantToGo(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

  function dontWantToGo(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
  <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwzxVWi.jpg ">
  <!-- Open heart icon -->
  <a href = "#" onClick = "wantToGo(4)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
  <!-- Closed heart icon -->
  <a href = "#" onClick = "dontWantToGo(4)"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "color:red;"></i></a> 
</div>

<div class='col-md-4'>
  <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/Ohk2jxC.jpg ">
  <a href = "#" onClick = "wantToGo(5)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
  <a href = "#" onClick = "dontWantToGo(5)"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "color:red;"></i></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Oh dear!! Have you even tried googling this?

Comment: what are the scenarios? On click of first link, what are you hiding? what are you showing? What do the wantToGo and dontWantToGo represent? Please Elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have 2 separated `div`s. You can just change the class in order to "switch" the icon (FontAwesome allows you to do that).

```js
function switchHeart(el){
 var icon = el.querySelector('.fa');//Get the i element from his parent
 var opened = 'fa-heart-o';
 var closed = 'fa-heart';

 icon.classList.toggle(opened);
 icon.classList.toggle(closed);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" onclick="switchHeart(this)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red"></i></a>
```

- `this` in the onclick event listener allows you to reference the element triggering the click event.
- In the function, we get the `i` child element from the parent that triggered the event.
- A pair of variables with the classes for opened/closed heart.
- We toggle each class, so if the `opened` class is present, we remove it. The same with the `closed` class.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have an id associated for each particular heart image (not show in your code). So, you will reference it by that `id` (using `document.getElementById(2)` code). The image icon you will change by changing it's (DOM element's) `src` (source) attribute.

```
<script >
function wantToGo(id)
{
  document.getElementById(id).src='openheart.png';
}

function dontWantToGo(id)
{
  document.getElementById(id).src='closedheart.png';
}
</script>
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gwzxVWi.jpg" id="1">
  <a href = "#" onClick = "wantToGo(1)">...</a>
  <a href = "#" onClick = "dontWantToGo(1)">...</a> 
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gwzxVWi.jpg" id="2">
  <a href = "#" onClick = "wantToGo(2)">...</a>
  <a href = "#" onClick = "dontWantToGo(2)">...</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Javascript :

```
function wantToGo(id) {

        id.nextSibling.style.visibility="true";
        id.style.visibility="false";


      }

      function dontWantToGo(id) {

        id.previousSibling.style.visibility="true";
        id.style.visibility="false";

      }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class='col-md-4'>
                <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwzxVWi.jpg ">

                    <!-- Open heart icon -->
                    <a href = "#" onClick = "wantToGo(this)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>

                    <!-- Closed heart icon -->
                    <a href = "#" onClick = "dontWantToGo(this)"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "color:red;visibility:hidden;"></i></a> 



          </div>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
                <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/Ohk2jxC.jpg ">


                    <a href = "#" onClick = "wantToGo(this)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>


                    <a href = "#" onClick = "dontWantToGo(this)"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "color:red;visibility:hidden;"></i></a> 



          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

few additions to your markup and script, check below:

HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gwzxVWi.jpg">
      <!-- Open heart icon -->
      <a href="#" onClick="wantToGo(event, 4)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <!-- Closed heart icon -->
      <a href="#" onClick="dontWantToGo(event, 4)"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "color:red;"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ohk2jxC.jpg">
      <a href="#" onClick="wantToGo(event, 5)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      <a href="#" onClick="dontWantToGo(event, 5)"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style = "color:red;"></i></a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function wantToGo(me, id) {
    me.target.className = toggleClass(me.target.className);
}
function dontWantToGo(me, id) {
    me.target.className = toggleClass(me.target.className);
}
function toggleClass(val) {
  return (val === "fa fa-heart-o") ? "fa fa-heart" : "fa fa-heart-o";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html` `<input type="checkbox">`, `<label>` elements; `css` `position:absolute`, `z-Index`, `:checked`, adjacent sibling selector, `background`, `url()`, `:hover` to set `cursor` to `pointer`

```css
.col-md-4 {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-Index: 1;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /* `url("/path/to/open-heart/image") */
  background: blue;
  z-Index: 0;
}
:checked + label {
  /* `url("/path/to/closed-heart/image") */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label></label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label></label>
</div>
```